# Dealing with "\n\t\t" with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following substring in the string str(dList):

```
"addressRegion">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMA\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</span>
```

I am trying to use re.search to pull out "MA" using this:

```
state = re.search(r'"addressRegion">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(.+?)\n\t',str(dList))
```

however, that doesn't seem to work. I understand this is possibly because of the the way "/" is handled. I can't figure out how to deal with this.

Comment: You are using regex to parse HTML? [Please don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2308683)

Comment: I am actually using BeautifulSoup, I am using regex for the finer details. (substrings).

Comment: Can you get the text within that span tag? Then strip the whitespace of `\t` and `\n`?

Answer (score 2):

Regex is **really** not necessary

```
In [22]: str = '<span class="addressRegion">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMA\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</span>'

In [23]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [24]: soup = BeautifulSoup(str, 'html.parser')

In [25]: soup.text
Out[25]: u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMA\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'

In [26]: soup.text.strip()
Out[26]: u'MA'
```

Comment: I agree, The no regex solution is probably the better approach.

Comment: The out at soup.text is u'\\n\\t\\t\\t instead of u'\n\t\t\t and so, soup.text.strip() doesn't do anything. But yes, I can see how this a much better approach.

Comment: @krthkskmr - Whatever you are viewing that in is escaping the backslashes

Answer (score 1):

**update**
This is how you *could* do it if you really wanted to use regex, but I think @cricket_007's solution is the better approach.

All you need to do is to escape the backslash with another backslash. You can also get rid of the repetitions of '\t':

```
>>> s = '"addressRegion">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMA\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</span>'
>>> re.search('.*\\n(\\t)+(.*?)\\n(\\t)+.*',s).group(2)
'MA'
```

Comment: I'll revoke my downvote for at least accepting regex is not the recommended approach. :)